# Android close custom dialog within layout

Tags: android, dialog

I am looking for a way to close a custom dialog with a button that is inside the xml used in the dialog, alternatively closing it by pressing anywhere on the dialog. What I have is this; a layout with a Image Button that brings up the custom dialog with the content. I have setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); and that works, but I need the dialog to fill up most of the screen and it can be hard for the user to click in the small space that is available. So how do I do this?

My java code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class Rose extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(
        ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.rose);

        ImageButton b = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Dialog d1 = new Dialog(Rose.this);
                d1.setContentView(R.layout.tariquet);
                d1.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
                d1.show();  


            }
        });
    }

}
```

And my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:minHeight="1100dp" 
    android:minWidth="650dp">
    <ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/rose_tariquet" 
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ImageView>
    <Button android:text="X" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/button1" 
    android:layout_width="55dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="right"></Button>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
Button close;
TextView tv;
public CustomizeDialog(Context context,String Stringcontent) {
    super(context);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);      
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_diolog_main);
    tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.content);
    tv.setText(Stringcontent);
    close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.close);
    close.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {       
    if (v == close)
        dismiss();
}
}
```

called:

```
CustomizeDialog customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(CustomDialog.this,"clickme");
customizeDialog.show();
```

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work, not sure what I'm doing wrong. I created a new Java file called CustomizeDialog using the code above and replacing the IDs.

Comment: Where do I put that? I get a bunch of syntax errors if I put it in at the end of the code.